# Master Page Help

Tags: asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I am sort of new to the whole html and css scene! All I really want to do is have a background, the content placer in the middle, and a header. An example would be this:

http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/3751/38244782.png

Would someone please help me do something really simple like this? Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow might not be the place for you. Some input of you is required, also, SO is not the place to discuss this kind of simple questions. I advice to google.

Comment: why? It's not that hard is it? I have tried smashing magazine and other places, bah fine ok.

Comment: @Sharepoint: There's definitely a specific niche of questions for which SO is designed, and this one is kind of on the fringe so you may find help but you just as easily may not.  We generally deal with questions such as "this is what I'm trying to do, here's some code, this is the behavior I'm expecting, but this is the behavior I'm seeing, please help" whereas this question is more along the lines of "I'd like to learn how to do something, please help me along."  It's not the broadest question we've seen, but it's still on the broad side.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place for simple questions? Why? The simpler the better because it's the simple stuff that holds people up when they're genuinely trying to learn. We all started at the same level ;-)

Comment: +1 for David's constructive comment

Comment: +1 for david who says what I meant. @IrishChieftain, partly true but I would still love to see a somewhat more constructive OP with things tried or whatever. If everyone starts posting questions which are very easy to google in 1 hit it will probably "overflow" SO and questions with a lot of time in them will be missed. IMHO SO never has been the place to start the first day of your career, though it is for the second and up.

Comment: @bastijn I agree. I think we need to encourage beginners who are conscientious. I'm also guilty of "lazy posting" but I'm reading Skeet's guidelines to try and get myself out of that habit ;-) http://bit.ly/d1Oagz @Sharepoint, this is a really good link :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="headElement">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="marginWrapper">
           <!-- Header -->
           <div id="pageHeader">Header</div>
           <!-- Body -->
           <div id="pageBody">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server" />
           </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

then use this as CSS

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
}

body 
{
    background: #F4F4F4 url('/_assets/images/backgr_grad.png') repeat-x 0 0;
    color: #284E98;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#marginWrapper 
{
   width: 950px;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 1;
}


#pageHeader
{
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 76px;
    max-height: 76px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#pageBody
{
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```